# VS 2013 - MS Build Issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded from VS2010 to VS2013 on our project.

When trying to run our web deploy I now receive this error:

> "C:\G\ectc.proj" (Deploy target) (1) -> "C:\G\Source\Web\Web.csproj (ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplicatio n target) (14:18) -> C:\g\Source\Web\Web.csproj : error MSB4057: The target "_CopyWeb Application" does not exist in the project.

It's strange, If i checkout the code before the upgrade and run the same build command which is:

> msbuild ctc.proj /t:Deploy

It work's fine, But doesnt if i run the that command on the VS 2013 code base.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try pre-processing ctc.proj from the 2010 environment and the 2013 environment to determine which target files are missing, or what's occuring in the 2013 deployment and failing to resolve the targets file containing CopyWebApplication.

In the 2013 environment use:

```
msbuild ctc.proj /pp >2013.txt
```

In the 2010 environment use:

```
msbuild ctc.proj /pp >2013.txt
```

I'm guessing it's using an incorrect path to the target containing CopyWebApplications.