# .targets file for "Package" using only VS2013

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2013

i am currently creating a new build machine for VS2013 and .NET 4.5. I have NOT installed any of the previous versions of visual studio. I have an msbuild step I am trying to execute using /target:package. This fails without anything else installed with this error:

```
MSB4057: The target "Package" does not exist in the project.
```

Is there something I can do to fix this without installing old version of visual studio?

EDIT: I can find the files that I am missing but I don't want to know that, I'm interested in what the solution is since I don't have those files and don't want to install them, hence not just installed the older versions of visual studio.

EDIT: I am trying to package a csproj file that is a web application for web deploy.

Comment: Similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760259/vs-2013-ms-build-issues

Comment: This would entail using msbuild.exe to preprocess a project file.  This will import all pertinent .targets files and allow you to quickly CTRL+F to determine which targets file contained the "Packages" target.  Then you'd do the same on your VS2013 machine and see if it's attempting to load a missing targets.

Comment: There are several targets named "Package", don't force us to guess what kind of project this is and what kind of tools version it targets.

Answer (score 2):

For VS2013 you need to do it slightly differently...

1. If you don't want VS on the build machine install Build Tools 2013
2. Create a publishing profile (Publish context menu in VS), called say Release
3. Command line looks as follows..

   msbuild  /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=Package /p:PublishProfile=Release

Comment: What would you use to purely save the package to a location?  This is what I used to be able to accomplish.  I have it building the package however I can't find the property to give a saving location in the msbuild documentation.